# Get content of URL after the page has loaded

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I need to fetch a string in a `<div>` from an URL. I'm using Ajax and PHP to retrieve the information. I've managed to collect the "correct" data.

The issue is, the data I'm collecting - which is a number -, is `0`in the beginning and directly updates to `103` or some other random number once the page has fully loaded. I need the second one.
This is because the website I'm retrieving data from is made in ReactJS and updates that number dynamically with JSX.

I somehow need to get the data **after** the page has loaded all of it's content.

**Long story short:**
How can I fetch data from an URL **after** the page in question has loaded its full content by javascript?

My code:

**/gethtml.php**

```
function curl_get_file_contents($URL)
{
    $c = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);
    $contents = curl_exec($c);
    curl_close($c);

    if ($contents) return $contents;
    else return FALSE;
}
function get_number(){
    $url = "https://www.example.com";
    $html = curl_get_file_contents($url);
    $dom = new DOMDocument;
    @$dom->loadHTML($html);
    $divs = $dom->getElementsByTagName('div');
    $compare_string = "someClassName";
    
    foreach ($divs as $div){
        $c = $div->getAttribute("class");
        if(strpos($c, $compare_string) !== false) {
            return $c;
        }             
    }
}
$num= get_number();
echo json_encode(array("value"=>$num));
```

**Javascript / Ajax**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){

    $.ajax({
        url:"gethtml.php", 
        type: "post",   
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {},
        success:function(result){
            console.log(result.value);
        }
    });

});
```

**Visual example**

[image: Collecting data]

Comment: I'm not sure why this has been downvoted. But at the moment, you're not gonna have much luck pulling the raw data of the URL. Even if you can simulate its JS file, it's gonna take more time. What I suggest is tracing the functions that change that "0" to what ever number it should be. If it's an API call, check the networks tab in dev tools to see how to call it.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not an API call. They do not offer it as of now.
Can I trace the function without access to an API?

Comment: If it's a function available in a JS file that that site pulls, you recreate the logic that returns the number. I don't have much to suggest aside from looking for React debugging tools or reading the JS logic itself.

Answer (score 0):

Long story short: You should not manually update "views" that are controlled by React.

Even if you execute your code AFTER the page was initially rendered, there is the chance that the [state](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) of the component will change because of some reason and your change will be overwritten yet again.